# Error al desplegar Spring Boot Rest Sencillo . Java,

Tags: java, spring-boot

He estado haciendo un ejercicio sencillo de un servicio web implementando Spring Boot. Sin embargo tengo un problema al compilar mediante Spring Tool 3.9.6.RELEASE en Eclipse Photon.

Adjunto el codigo, al finalizar se añade la excepcion.

**SpringRestMySqlAplicacion.java**

```
package com.unbosque.edu.webservice.proyecto;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringRestMySqlAplicacion 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringRestMySqlAplicacion .class, args);
    }
}
```

**UsuarioControlador.java**

```
package com.unbosque.edu.webservice.proyecto.controlador;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.unbosque.edu.webservice.proyecto.modelo.Usuario;
import com.unbosque.edu.webservice.proyecto.repositorio.UsuarioRepositorio;


@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8081")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/proyecto")
public class UsuarioControlador {

@Autowired
UsuarioRepositorio repositorio;

@GetMapping("/usuarios/obtener/todos")
public List<Usuario> obtenerTodosLosUsuarios(){
    List<Usuario> usuarios = new ArrayList<>();
    repositorio.findAll().forEach(usuarios::add);
    return usuarios;
}

@PostMapping("/usaurios/crear")
public Usuario crearUsuario(@RequestBody Usuario usuario) {
    Usuario usuario2 = repositorio.save(new Usuario(usuario.getCedula(),     usuario.getContrasena(), usuario.getTipo()));
    return usuario2;
}

@DeleteMapping("/usuarios/eliminar/{cedula}/")
public ResponseEntity<String> eliminarUsuario(@PathVariable("cedula") int cedula){
    repositorio.deleteById(cedula);
    return new ResponseEntity("El usuario" + cedula + " fue eliminado.", HttpStatus.OK);
}

@DeleteMapping("/usuarios/eliminar/todos")
public ResponseEntity<String> eliminarTodosLosUsuario(){
    repositorio.deleteAll();
    return new ResponseEntity("Todos los usuarios fueron eliminados.", HttpStatus.OK);
}

@GetMapping("/usuarios/cedula/{cedula}")
public List<Usuario> buscarPorCedula(@PathVariable("cedula") int cedula){
    List<Usuario> usuarios = repositorio.buscarPorCedula(cedula);
    return usuarios;
}

@PutMapping("/usuarios/actualizar/{idUsuario}")
public ResponseEntity<Usuario> actualizarUsuario(@PathVariable("cedula") int cedula, @RequestBody Usuario usuario){
    Optional<Usuario> usuarioData = repositorio.findById(cedula);

    if(usuarioData.isPresent()) {
        Usuario usuario2 = usuarioData.get();
        usuario2.setCedula(usuario.getCedula());
        usuario2.setContrasena(usuario.getContrasena());
        usuario2.setTipo(usuario.getTipo());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(repositorio.save(usuario2), HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
}
```

**UsuarioRepositorio.java**

```
package com.unbosque.edu.webservice.proyecto.repositorio;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.unbosque.edu.webservice.proyecto.modelo.Usuario;

public interface UsuarioRepositorio extends CrudRepository<Usuario, Integer>    {
    List<Usuario> buscarPorCedula(int cedula);
}
```

**Usuario.java**

```
package com.unbosque.edu.webservice.proyecto.modelo;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Usuario")
public class Usuario {

@Id
@Column(name="cedula")
private int cedula;

@Column(name="contrasena")
private String contrasena;

@Column(name="tipo")
private int tipo;

public Usuario() {
}

public Usuario(int cedula, String contrasena, int tipo) {
    this.cedula = cedula;
    this.contrasena = contrasena;
    this.tipo = tipo;
}

public int getCedula() {
    return cedula;
}

public void setCedula(int cedula) {
    this.cedula = cedula;
}

public String getContrasena() {
    return contrasena;
}

public void setContrasena(String contrasena) {
    this.contrasena = contrasena;
}

public int getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(int tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.unbosque.edu.webservice</groupId>
<artifactId>proyecto</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>proyecto</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=7834426
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usuarios?useSSL=false
```

**Excepciones al compilar por Spring Tool App**

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-10-08 22:01:20.778 ERROR 15764 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed...

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usuarioRepositorio': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.unbosque.edu.webservice.proyecto.repositorio.UsuarioRepositorio.buscarPorCedula(int)! No property buscarPorCedula found for type Usuario!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]...

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.unbosque.edu.webservice.proyecto.repositorio.UsuarioRepositorio.buscarPorCedula(int)! No property buscarPorCedula found for type Usuario!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:82) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]...

Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property buscarPorCedula found for type Usuario!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.(PropertyPath.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]...

Agradezco una notación para el problema que estoy cometiendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property buscarPorCedula found for type Usuario`

Spring JPA usa ciertos convenios para los nombres de los métodos de tus repositorios. Si lo que quieres es tener un método para buscar por el atributo `cedula` de tu clase Usuario, sin tener que declarar la query que se ha de ejecutar, lo que has de hacer es llamarlo `findByCedula`. Vamos, que tu repositorio quedaría así:

```
package com.unbosque.edu.webservice.proyecto.repositorio;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.unbosque.edu.webservice.proyecto.modelo.Usuario;

public interface UsuarioRepositorio extends CrudRepository<Usuario, Integer> {
    List<Usuario> findByCedula(int cedula);
}
```

Si realmente necesitas que el método se llame `buscarPorCedula`, entonces tú has de proporcionarle la query a Spring para que sepa cómo resolver esa consulta. Para eso, has de anotar el método con `@Query` y quedaría algo así:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM Usuario u where u.cedula = ?1")
List<Usuario> buscarPorCedula(int cedula);
```